# Can i create a new field into the comment section of the Issue into the JIRA?

Tags: rest, c#-4.0, jira, jira-rest-api

i am working on integration jira with liquidPlanner, i need to check if comments into the jIRA exist or not, for that i need to make some uniquness for both applications, so planned the comment id of LP to map with customfield_xxxxx of jira. But i am don't know how to create a customfield in comment section of JIRA,

if anyone know please let me know, it will save my time.

Answer (score 0):

From the rest api we can't create the customField_xxx into the comment section. We can create the customField_xxx from the UI while you are administrator of the JIRA.